# Historgram function for matplotlib returning weird y-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to understand the `matplotlib.hist` function. I have the following data:

```
cs137_count = np.array([this has a size of 750 and integers in the range from 1820 to 1980])
plt.figure()
plt.hist(cs137_count, density=True, bin = 50)  
plt.ylabel('Distribution')
plt.xlabel('Counts');
```

but the plot it provides has weird values for the `y-axis` in the range from `0 - 0.016` which makes no sense and I am not sure why it returns those values? I have attached an image of the plot below.

[image: Image of plot]

Comment: `[this has a size of 750 and integers in the range from 1820 to 1980]`--> `np.random.random_integers(1820,1980,750)`

Comment: Y of 0.016 for x=1900 means there is about 1.6% chance that x=1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `density=True`. From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

> density: bool, optional
>
> If True, the first element of the return tuple
> will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., the
> area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1. This is achieved
> by dividing the count by the number of observations times the bin
> width and not dividing by the total number of observations. If stacked
> is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.
>
> Default is False.